# Discord bot stops sending messages, but does not throw an error or crash

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been working on a discord bot in python using pycharm that creates a webhook then sends a message with that webhook. It works fine for a bit then stops sending messages. I created a log to see if it wasn't even entering the on_message event, but it is still entering it. I have noticed if I stop the bot for a longer period of time, or restart my computer then it usually works again, but I have not been able to find out why its happening or a legit solution. I will put the code below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import discord

TOKEN = 'Was not sure if I should put this on stack'

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('{0.user} is locked and loaded'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel})')

    hook = await message.channel.create_webhook(name="HookTest7033")

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if user_message.lower() == '!hooktest':
        await hook.send("Hello")
        await hook.send("Bye")
        hooks = await message.channel.webhooks()
        for webhook in hooks:
            await webhook.delete()
        return

    if message.author == await client.fetch_user(User ID goes here):
        await hook.send("Test response")
        hooks = await message.channel.webhooks()
        for webhook in hooks:
            await webhook.delete()
        return

    if message.author == await client.fetch_user(User ID goes here):
        await hook.send("Test response")
        hooks = await message.channel.webhooks()
        for webhook in hooks:
            await webhook.delete()
        return


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: did you get any rate limit message?

Comment: no keep_alive() method?

Comment: Why would he need a `keep_alive()` method? @DragonInTraining

Comment: How long does it usually take before it stops sending messages? a few minutes? hours?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński the `keep_alive()` method is used for discord bots on REPLIT using Uptime Robot. It keeps the bot online 24/7 by pinging it.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński my bad, I got it wrong and thought this was through Replit.

Comment: Is OP using repl.it?

Comment: it usually stops sending messages in about an hour or so, sometimes it is shorter and sometimes its longer

Comment: @DragonInTraining I'm using pycharm, I thought that would be better for a bot. Do you think I should use repl.it?

Comment: @PranavaMohan I get no messages when the bot stops sending messages, it still enters the on_message event because it continues to log messages with the print statement, it just stops sending messages in the discord server